# How can I locate a onmouseover element using VBA?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a site and there is an element that if you move your mouse over it it displays some information in a bubble. I am using VBA to scrape the page but I don't know how to locate the specific element.

Looking at the source of the page I get this:

```php
<td class="right odds up">
<div onmouseout="delayHideTip()" onmouseover="page.hist(this,'P-0.00-00','1q3cfx2rrhkx0x3jtah',381,event,0,1)"
```

Providing some details, the following is the page I want to scrape: [match page.](http://www.oddsportal.com/baseball/usa/mlb-2014/arizona-diamondbacks-st-louis-cardinals-jeOoAP9r/) When you move your mouse over the arrows and the numbers a rectangle appears with some content. That's what I want to get.

My code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()

the_start:
Dim objIE As Object

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Visible = True

On Error Resume Next

objIE.Navigate ("http://www.oddsportal.com/baseball/usa/mlb-2014/arizona-diamondbacks-st-louis-cardinals-jeOoAP9r/")

Do
DoEvents
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        objIE.Quit
        Set objIE = Nothing
        GoTo the_start:
    End If
Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4



objIE.Document.all.Item
Dim js As Variant
js = page.hist(this,P-0.00-0-0,1q3cfx2rrhkx0x3jtah,381,event,0,1) ???
Call objIE.Document.parentWindow.execScript(js, "JavaScript")  ???

MsgBox "objIE.js"

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't access the website on my current network but I wonder if that tooltip information is stored elsewhere in the HTML?  I haven't worked with tooltip information like that often, but once I did and the information was in the HTML farther down the page, it just uses CSS and JS to control the display of the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim objIE, colTdNodes, i, objTdNode, objDivNode, strTooltipContent, objDispNode

    ' open the page
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "http://www.oddsportal.com/baseball/usa/mlb-2014/arizona-diamondbacks-st-louis-cardinals-jeOoAP9r/"
        ' wait until IE and the page are ready
        Do While .Busy Or Not .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        ' wait until the DOM is ready
        Do Until .document.readyState = "complete": DoEvents: Loop
        ' wait until the table is ready
        Do While TypeName(.document.getElementById("odds-data-table")) = "Null": DoEvents: Loop
    End With

    ' below is an example how to retrieve tooltips content

    ' get table target cells nodes collection
    Set colTdNodes = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("right odds")
    ' loop through each cell in collection
    For i = 0 To colTdNodes.Length - 1
        ' choose the cell from collection
        Set objTdNode = colTdNodes(i)
        ' get div node from the cell
        Set objDivNode = objTdNode.ChildNodes.Item(0)
        ' get the tooltip content
        strTooltipContent = GetTooltipContent(objDivNode)
        ' create new div node to display tooltip content
        Set objDispNode = objIE.document.createElement("div")
        ' add the created node into the cell
        objTdNode.appendChild objDispNode
        ' set id and style
        objDispNode.ID = "tooltip" & i
        objDispNode.Style.Background = "#ddd"
        objDispNode.Style.padding = "5px"
        objDispNode.Style.margin = "5px"
        ' display the tooltip content in the node
        objDispNode.innerHtml = strTooltipContent
    Next
    ' hide the last tooltip
    objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript "delayHideTip();", "javascript"
End Sub

Function GetTooltipContent(objNode)
    Dim objEventMouseOver, objTipNode, objDocument
    ' get document object
    Set objDocument = objNode.OwnerDocument
    ' create mouse event object
    Set objEventMouseOver = objDocument.createEvent("MouseEvents")
    ' setup mouseover event
    objEventMouseOver.initMouseEvent "mouseover", True, True, objDocument.parentWindow, 1, 12, 345, 7, 220, False, False, True, False, 0, ""
    ' send mouseover event to the div node
    ' support for dispatchEvent was added in IE9
    objNode.dispatchEvent objEventMouseOver
    ' retrieve appeared tooltip node
    Set objTipNode = objDocument.getElementById("tooltiptext")
    ' get tooltip html content
    GetTooltipContent = objTipNode.innerHtml
End Function
```